# Java EE eclipse project directory structure?

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, jakarta-ee

I am attempting to setup a sample dynamic web project in Eclipse using Java EE, Spring and Maven (using Nexus repository manager).  I was wondering if anybody knows the "best practice" directory structure that I should setup for an enterprise web app in Eclipse?  Should I just stick with the default structure that is setup for me?  I ask because looking around the internet I see wide variation (for instance, where the WEB-INF and META-INF folders are..if there is a 'war' directory etc.).  Thanks!

Comment: To make Eclipse and maven play better I'd suggest downloading the m2eclipse plugin, it's update site is http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/update/

Answer (score 7):

If you use Maven, I'd warmly recommend to just follow **Maven's convention**. This is the "best  practice" in Maven's world (and I don't see any good reasons to not do so, not following this advice will lead to more work).

One easy way to create a webapp project is to use the maven-archetype-webapp:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp \
                       -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app \
                       -DartifactId=my-webapp \
                       -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

(You can paste this command "as is" in a Linux shell; on Windows, type everything on single line without the `"\"`.)

And this is the structure you'll get:

```
my-webapp
|-- pom.xml
`-- src
    `-- main
        |-- resources
        `-- webapp
            |-- WEB-INF
            |   `-- web.xml
            `-- index.jsp
```

This layout is compliant with Eclipse WTP (whatever plugin you're using for the Eclipse integration). Just import this project into Eclipse and there you go.

If you have more specific question, feel free to ask (for example, most of time you don't have to worry about the `META-INF` directory, but put it under `src/main/resources` if really you need to have it).

Comment: Thanks! Can you please elaborate on using the "maven-archetype-webapp".  Is this some tool I can use to automatically generate this directory structure?

Comment: Yes, archetypes are "maven projects generators". Actually, I wrote the command just after mentioning it and showed the obtained structure. I thought this would be clear.

Comment: The link that I posted from Apache explains the entire directory structure standard.  Did you read it, Jim?

Comment: Also note that you can use "mvn archetype:generate" without further arguments to get interactive prompts for the rest of the information needed to generate an archetype.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Maven, it's best to follow [their convention](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

If you're using Spring, you don't need an EAR.  A WAR will do just fine.

A WAR file has a definite standard that you must follow.  As long as you can generate a proper WAR file, you can use any directory structure for your source code that makes sense to you.

I use something like this:

```
/project
+---/src (.java)
+---/test (TestNG .java here)
+---/test-lib (testNG JAR, Spring test JAR, etc.)
+---/resources (log4j.xml, etc.)
+---/web (root of web content here)
+---+---/WEB-INF
+---+---+---/classes (compile .java to this directory)
+---+---+---/lib (JAR files)
```

I use IntelliJ, so it creates an exploded WAR file as output for me.

I have an Ant build.xml that generally follows the IntelliJ directory structure.  You're welcome to crib it if you find it useful.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="xslt-converter" basedir="." default="package">

    <property name="version" value="1.6"/>
    <property name="haltonfailure" value="no"/>

    <property name="out" value="out"/>

    <property name="production.src" value="src"/>
    <property name="production.lib" value="lib"/>
    <property name="production.resources" value="config"/>
    <property name="production.classes" value="${out}/production/${ant.project.name}"/>

    <property name="test.src" value="test"/>
    <property name="test.lib" value="lib"/>
    <property name="test.resources" value="config"/>
    <property name="test.classes" value="${out}/test/${ant.project.name}"/>

    <property name="exploded" value="out/exploded/${ant.project.name}"/>
    <property name="exploded.classes" value="${exploded}/WEB-INF/classes"/>
    <property name="exploded.lib" value="${exploded}/WEB-INF/lib"/>

    <property name="reports.out" value="${out}/reports"/>
    <property name="junit.out" value="${reports.out}/junit"/>
    <property name="testng.out" value="${reports.out}/testng"/>

    <path id="production.class.path">
        <pathelement location="${production.classes}"/>
        <pathelement location="${production.resources}"/>
        <fileset dir="${production.lib}">
            <include name="**/*.jar"/>
            <exclude name="**/junit*.jar"/>
            <exclude name="**/*test*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <path id="test.class.path">                            
        <path refid="production.class.path"/>
        <pathelement location="${test.classes}"/>
        <pathelement location="${test.resources}"/>
        <fileset dir="${test.lib}">
            <include name="**/junit*.jar"/>
            <include name="**/*test*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <path id="testng.class.path">
        <fileset dir="${test.lib}">
            <include name="**/testng*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <available file="${out}" property="outputExists"/>

    <target name="clean" description="remove all generated artifacts" if="outputExists">
        <delete dir="${out}" includeEmptyDirs="true"/>
        <delete dir="${reports.out}" includeEmptyDirs="true"/>
    </target>

    <target name="create" description="create the output directories" unless="outputExists">
        <mkdir dir="${production.classes}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${test.classes}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${reports.out}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${junit.out}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${testng.out}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${exploded.classes}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${exploded.lib}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile" description="compile all .java source files" depends="create">
        <!-- Debug output
                <property name="production.class.path" refid="production.class.path"/>
                <echo message="${production.class.path}"/>
        -->
        <javac srcdir="src" destdir="${out}/production/${ant.project.name}" debug="on" source="${version}">
            <classpath refid="production.class.path"/>
            <include name="**/*.java"/>
            <exclude name="**/*Test.java"/>
        </javac>
        <javac srcdir="${test.src}" destdir="${out}/test/${ant.project.name}" debug="on" source="${version}">
            <classpath refid="test.class.path"/>
            <include name="**/*Test.java"/>
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="junit-test" description="run all junit tests" depends="compile">
        <!-- Debug output
                <property name="test.class.path" refid="test.class.path"/>
                <echo message="${test.class.path}"/>
        -->
        <junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="${haltonfailure}">
            <classpath refid="test.class.path"/>
            <formatter type="xml"/>
            <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${junit.out}">
                <fileset dir="${test.src}">
                    <include name="**/*Test.java"/>
                </fileset>
            </batchtest>
        </junit>
        <junitreport todir="${junit.out}">
            <fileset dir="${junit.out}">
                <include name="TEST-*.xml"/>
            </fileset>
            <report todir="${junit.out}" format="frames"/>
        </junitreport>
    </target>

    <taskdef resource="testngtasks" classpathref="testng.class.path"/>
    <target name="testng-test" description="run all testng tests" depends="compile">
        <!-- Debug output
                <property name="test.class.path" refid="test.class.path"/>
                <echo message="${test.class.path}"/>
        -->
        <testng classpathref="test.class.path" outputDir="${testng.out}" haltOnFailure="${haltonfailure}" verbose="2" parallel="methods" threadcount="50">
            <classfileset dir="${out}/test/${ant.project.name}" includes="**/*.class"/>
        </testng>
    </target>

    <target name="exploded" description="create exploded deployment" depends="testng-test">
        <copy todir="${exploded.classes}">
            <fileset dir="${production.classes}"/>
        </copy>
        <copy todir="${exploded.lib}">
            <fileset dir="${production.lib}"/>
        </copy>
    </target>

    <target name="package" description="create package file" depends="exploded">
        <jar destfile="${out}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${production.classes}" includes="**/*.class"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  So would you say that there really isn't a correct or "best practice" structure?

Comment: No general consensus.  Maven imposes one on you; I don't happen to appreciate that.  There's a definite fixed requirement for the WAR and EAR file, but as long as you can generate that you can do it any way that makes sense for you.

Comment: You of course can use Maven and override their default scheme if you like

Comment: Thanks for the update.  So if I'm using Maven AND Spring then it would be a good idea to follow the convention for Maven that you linked to?

Comment: Basically I was originally confused because it feels like all of the components of the project (the Eclipse IDE included) are competing for "their own" directory structure.  Maybe I'm wrong but it seems as if one component will ultimately have to be manually overridden to conform to a certain convention.